# Windows creates autorun.inf when mounting samba share

Tags: windows, samba

I'm running `samba` on my Linux machine.

When I mount a `samba` share from `Windows`, such as my home directory, a file named `autorun.inf` will be created inside the mount. It seems to be a text file but horribly disfigured and even `file` claims it to be a binary.

The file can be deleted of course but will be re-created every time `Windows` mounts the share.

Is there a way to get rid of that file permanently? Is it dangerous in some way?
Why would `Windows` create it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like that your Windows computer is infected with some kind of malware that creates the file automatically to all removable devices so that the malware can spread further.

Run a complete AV scan in Windows.

Comment: You were right, thank you. The MS Security Essentials removed the problem. So my question is obviously on the wrong site. Damn.